# GIMP 2.10.34 - How install compact installation silently

Tags: gimp, silent-install

Hi i use now command for Full silent Installation: "gimp-2.10.34-setup.exe" /verysilent /allusers /norestart /dir="c:\programy\gimp" but this is Full Installation. How run silently Compact instalation?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6WYf.png)

Clarification of the problem: I need a similar command to install GIMP in silent mode but the Compact version, which can be selected manually as shown in the picture. I described how to install the full version in the previous text and I want to install GIMP in Compact Mode in the same way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you're asking, "is there a command line option to specify the install type to compact"?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **/TYPE="COMPACT"** installation argument!

For example, my script line is this. It does what you want, and some other, very much needed quirks to allow a truly silent install.

```
gimpsetup.exe /VERYSILENT /NORESTART /TYPE="COMPACT" /MERGETASKS="desktopicon" /ALLUSERS /NOCLOSEAPPLICATIONS /NOCANCEL /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /LOG="%WINDIR%\Temp\GIMP-Install.log"
```